# diferencia en "IF" de archivos pdf, DOC, PPTX

Tags: php, pdf, if

necesito crear un "if" para diferenciar archivos pdf de doc y de pptx en php.

Gracias

Comment: Hola bienvenido. Por favor pon el código que llevas hasta ahora y señala dónde es que no puedes seguir.

Comment: @MiguelM te sugiero modifiques tu pregunta, lee [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. El formato actual no cumple con lo definido en el [help]

Comment: Has de mostrar lo intentado y qué errores te ha dado. Necesitamos esa informacion para ayudarte a resolver el problema, no hacertelo. Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías hacer algo así

```
$tipo_archivo = pathinfo('ruta/de/tu/archivo');

if($tipo_archivo['extension'] == 'pdf'){
    echo "el archivo es un PDF"
}

if($tipo_archivo['extension'] == 'doc'){
    echo "el archivo es un Documento"
}

if($tipo_archivo['extension'] == 'pptx'){
    echo "el archivo es un Documento de Power Point"
}
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos

Comment: Amigo, estaba revisando el código y la variable $tipo_archivo la esta tomando como file, no esta tomando la propiedad del filetype

Comment: Te pregunto, estás subiendo el archivo desde algún formulario ?

Comment: no, desde un servidor local, y validando las propiedades de filetype(), el devuelve fifo, char, dir, block, link, file, socket y unknown

Comment: Entonces puedes usar pathinfo() y comparar directamente con la extensión del archivo

Comment: Te edité la respuesta de como sería con pathinfo()

Comment: @CamiloVasquez Es mejor que __no respondas__ a las preguntas mal formadas. Y si vas a responder es mejor hacerlo de forma completa, es decir, que no requieran ampliaciones o aclaraciones. Consulta la guía [_"Cómo escribir una buena respuesta"_](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Jorgesys no sabía que no se podía responder a las preguntas mal formuladas aún cuando uno las entiende, y en lo de mi respuesta, hay muchas formas de hacer las cosas, la primera forma no le funcionó entonces le mostré una segunda, si uno coloca todas las formas posibles quedaría una respuesta muy larga, entonces que se hace ahí? Gracias por las aclaraciones

Comment: @CamiloVasquez No hay impedimento para responder, pero generalmente no hay una respuesta concreta para este tipo de preguntas que no cumplen lo definido en [ask], regularmente se tienen que pedir aclaraciones y estas aclaraciones y especificaciones deberían venir en la pregunta y no comentarios o respuestas. Si una pregunta se realiza como describe el [help] es una pregunta que puede ayudar a otros usuarios que es lo que busca el sitio, no únicamente al OP. Para que el sitio tenga contenido de calidad es bueno orientar a los nuevos usuarios indicándoles como deben realizar una buena pregunta.